# NSFileManager creating folder (Cocoa error 513.)

Tags: iphone, nsfilemanager

I'm trying to create a folder inside the /sounds folder of my app.

```
-(void)productPurchased:(UAProduct*) product {
    NSLog(@"[StoreFrontDelegate] Purchased: %@ -- %@", product.productIdentifier, product.title);

    NSFileManager *manager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSString *bundleRoot = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];

    NSError *error;

    NSString *dataPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/sounds/%@", bundleRoot, product.title];

    if (![manager fileExistsAtPath:dataPath isDirectory:YES]) {
        [manager createDirectoryAtPath:dataPath withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:&error];
        NSLog(@"Creating folder");
    }

    NSLog(@"%@", error);
}
```

But I get this error:

```
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=513 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 513.)" UserInfo=0x175120 {NSFilePath=/var/mobile/Applications/D83FDFF9-2600-4056-9047-05F82633A2E4/App.app/sounds/Test Tones, NSUnderlyingError=0x117520 "The operation couldn’t be completed. Operation not permitted"}
```

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

If you search Google on the error domain [`NSCocoaErrorDomain`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Constants/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSCocoaErrorDomain) you find that the code `513` translates to the error [`NSFileWriteNoPermissionError`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Constants/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSFileWriteNoPermissionError).

This provides you with the critical clue for solving this problem:

> [This is the bundle directory containing the application itself. Because an application must be signed, you must not make changes to the contents of this directory at runtime. Doing so may prevent your application from launching later.](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/RuntimeEnvironment/RuntimeEnvironment.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH2-SW10)

Specifically, you cannot modify the contents of a compiled app's bundle folder. This is because the bundle is the compiled application.

When you eventually distribute the app through the iTunes App Store, the application has a digital signature that validates the contents of the app. This signature is generated at compile time.

If you try to change the bundle after compilation, the app changes and the digital signature is no longer valid. This invalidates the application — who knows what code is in there, right? — and so Apple has set up iOS to throw an error if you try to modify the application.

Instead of writing to the bundle, your app can write to [one of three accepted app-specific folders](https://developer.apple.com/icloud/documentation/data-storage/): `<Application_Home>/Documents`, `<Application_Home>/tmp` and `<Application_Home>/Library/Caches`.

Most likely, you will want to write to the `<Application_Home>/Documents` folder.

These folders are only accessible to your app. No other app can access the contents of these folders. (Likewise, your app cannot access another app's folders.)

You can set up your app to allow the end user to manage access to file data through iTunes, via [desktop file sharing support](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/StandardBehaviors/StandardBehaviors.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW10).

Comment: Thanks you for you answer Alex, if you can, update the last link because the page doesn't exist anymore!

Comment: Interestingly (at least with Xcode 6 & iOS 8) you CAN create directories in the bundle on the simulator, but the same code will fail on device.

Comment: ^re: Jared Egan, this is still true with the simulator for Xcode 8 & iOS 10

Comment: @Alex Reynolds `Documents, Temp and Cache` link is dead

Comment: @JaredEgan This was causing me a headache for 2 hours...
Instead of writing to .applicationDirectory you should write to .applicationSupportDirectory

Answer (score 8):

This is because you should never modify the bundle of your application at runtime. Instead, you should have a folder elsewhere where you can add resources.

EDIT:
The error you are seeing is most likely because you cannot write to the bundle.

Comment: +1 As part of the iOS security model, you cannot modify the app bundle after the app has been compiled. This prevents the possibility of malware modifying apps after install. Files generated at runtime should be saved to the either the Documents folder of the Library folder in the app's directory. The latter is preferred for files the user will never access by any means other than the app itself.

Answer (score 5):

I encounter the same problem, when using a *Log* library. Finally, it's path format problem. Check the `dataPath` format. If it is `Case 1`, it is valid. In my case, it's `Case 2`, so I failed to create directory.

```
// Case 1
/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/5FB2CD2D-91DC-4FB2-8D6F-06369C70BB4A/Library/Caches/AppLogs

// Case 2, invalid format
file://var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/5FB2CD2D-91DC-4FB2-8D6F-06369C70BB4A/Library/Caches/AppLogs
```

If the `dataPath` has a prefix, ex: `file://`, it is **invalid**.

---

As for an instance of `NSURL`, `path` will return the string like `case 1`, and `absolutePath` will return the string like `case 2`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still not totally clear on the meaning of the 513 error in my case, but I was getting it when just trying to read an opened file URL using `[NSFileHandle fileHandleForReadingFromURL:theUrl error:&err ]`.

I realized from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57973541/408877) that with iOS 13, I now need to use `startAccessingSecurityScopedResource` to access external files that are opened in the app.  When I wrapped my file calls as follows, then the error 513 stopped occurring:

```
if( [myURL startAccessingSecurityScopedResource] ) 
{
    NSFileHandle* myFile = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForReadingFromURL:myURL error:&err ];
    // ...Do file reads here...
    [theUrl stopAccessingSecurityScopedResource];
}
```