# Take Photos Within Application Saving

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiimagepickercontroller

I am trying to take photos within my application  and save them to a path with two dates (to specify when the photo was taken).

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    UIImage *image;
    image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, nil, nil, nil); //save to photo album
    NSString *pathString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Photos/%@/%@.png",timeStarted,[NSDate date]]; //create path
    NSString *savePath = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:pathString];
    //write the files!
    [UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) writeToFile:savePath atomically:YES];
}
```

When I check the folder `@"Photos/%@",timeStarted` it shows up as empty. What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**:

Here is my new code for testing purposes:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    //Create the image and save it to the photo album
    UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, nil, nil, nil);

    //Create the directory and add the file name to it
    NSString *fileName = @"Test.png";
    NSString *directory = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Photos"];
    NSString *fullPath = [directory stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];
    NSLog(@"Full path: %@", fullPath);

    //Save "image" to the file path
    [UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) writeToFile:fullPath atomically:YES];

    //START CHECKING : Log to check if anything was saved
    NSError *error;
    NSFileManager *fileMgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSLog(@"Photos directory: %@", [fileMgr contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:directory error:&error]);
    //END CHECKING

    [camera dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

And my `NSLog` reads:

```
[640:707] Full path: /var/mobile/Applications/3EEDBD68-5496-458D-9EF0-062746847C83/Photos/Test.png
[640:707] Photos directory: (null)
```

Comment: Have you succeefully saved this image to Photo Album?

Comment: Yes, it saves as intended to the photo album.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your pathString contains an invalid path. If you NSLog your path string it will look something like this

```
Photos/2011-11-16 20:16:16 +0000/2011-11-16 20:16:16 +0000.png
```

Try saving it using a regular path such as `Photo.png`. If this works it will indicate that it is a problem with the path. After this try using `NSDateFormatter` to output the dates as a string that is a valid path.

Comment: Still getting (null) when I list the contents of the directory. I am saving it as `Photos/1.png` and when I check `Photos` and/or `Photos/` (note the forward slash), it returns as null.

Comment: Edited to show the code that I use to check the file path. Maybe I'm just checking it wrong.

Comment: Don't use a slash, that is used as a directory separator. If you want to create a directory use the `createDirectoryAtPath:withIntermediateDirectories:` method on `NSFileManager`

Comment: You need to create the Photos directory before you can save files to it.

Comment: After trying it out and logging the error (and a lot of Googling), turns out I cannot create a folder outside of three folders until my application is signed. See accepted answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3439408/nsfilemanager-creating-folder-cocoa-error-513