# Couldn't create log directory

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, ipad, cocoa-touch

When I test my application on iPad it run perfectly i.e. call the database , create folder and perform other task  but in console it show me

> 2015-05-12 11:25:32.478 MyApp[291:19680] [PLLogging] Couldn't create log directory: The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 513.).

When I search, found this answer [NSFileManager creating folder (Cocoa error 513.)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3439408/nsfilemanager-creating-folder-cocoa-error-513)

But not abel to remove this.
Also when I shutdown and restart the iPad this line is not show

**Question:**

1. Why i get this statement in console?
2. The above statement can crash my app in future?
3. How to remove Cocoa error 513 ?

Here is my code to calling the database

```
let fileManager = NSFileManager()
var Sourcepath = NSBundle.mainBundle().resourcePath?.stringByAppendingPathComponent("DataBase.db");
let docsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask, true)[0] as! String
let databaseStr = "DataBase.db"
let dbPath = docsPath.stringByAppendingPathComponent(databaseStr)
println(dbPath)    
if(fileManager .fileExistsAtPath(dbPath) == false) {

    var error:NSError?
    fileManager.copyItemAtPath(Sourcepath!, toPath: dbPath, error: &error)
    println(error)
}
```

and here is a functions which create a logs folder

```
func CreateLog(Log:String)
{
    autoreleasepool{

        var formatter:NSDateFormatter! = NSDateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd";
        var DateString = formatter.stringFromDate(NSDate()).stringByAppendingString("_tempLogs")
        formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";
        var FileManager:NSFileManager! = NSFileManager.defaultManager()

        var LogFolder = NSBundle.mainBundle().resourcePath?.stringByAppendingPathComponent("Logs")
        let searchPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask, true)[0] as! String
        let LogStr = "Logs"
        let LogFolderPath = searchPath.stringByAppendingPathComponent(LogStr)

        if(FileManager.fileExistsAtPath(LogFolderPath) == false)
        {
            var error:NSError?
            FileManager.createDirectoryAtPath(LogFolderPath, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil, error: &error)

        }
        var LogPath = LogFolderPath.stringByAppendingPathComponent(DateString).stringByAppendingPathExtension("txt")
        var WriteString = (formatter.stringFromDate(NSDate()).stringByAppendingString(" ").stringByAppendingString(Log).stringByAppendingString("\n"));
        var Data = WriteString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        if(!FileManager.fileExistsAtPath(LogPath!))
        {
            FileManager.createFileAtPath(LogPath!, contents: Data, attributes: nil)
        }
        else
        {
            var output = NSFileHandle(forWritingAtPath: LogPath!);
            output?.seekToEndOfFile();
            output?.writeData(Data!);
            output?.closeFile()
            output = nil
        }
        formatter = nil
        FileManager = nil

    }

}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3439408/nsfilemanager-creating-folder-cocoa-error-513?lq=1

Comment: I have the same error message in Objc when I use the method "writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum" of the ALAssetsLibrary. And I do not use any log directory in my app....

Comment: Hi patrick is you find solution?

Comment: Always print out the `error`, don't just ignore the variable there. It usually contains relevant information.

Comment: Try to put your logs into Caches directory (`NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.CachesDirectory, NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask, true)[0] as! String`), which is the only correct place for logs. Will this fix your issue?

Never write any data to Documents directory, it's for user-generated content only. Also this might be a reason for rejecting your app from the appstore because Documents content is synced via iCloud.

Answer (score 1):

The 513 is a permission issue (NSFileWriteNoPermissionError).

Try to println the LogFolderPath and double check if it is correct (or post it here the result).

D.

Comment: checked the  LogFolderPath it will successfully created and update every time a run the app . The problem is when i run it on my actual device(Ipad) it just print   2015-05-12 11:25:32.478 MyApp[291:19680] [PLLogging] Couldn't create log directory: The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 513.). doesnot show its error or warning?

Comment: Does this error appear in a real device, in the simulator or both? If just in Simulator, have you tried to reset the simulator to initial settings? (in the Simulator menu bar choose "iOS Simulator" -> "Reset Content and Settings")

Comment: yes, after restart , first 3 to 4 build it will not show message and after that it will show message again

Comment: doh... it appears to be an iOS bug... is the device's firmware up to date (8.3.1)?

Comment: my device version is 8.3(12F69)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @mpromonet It seems to have found an underlying error and it *does* at least answer question 1: It gives an explanation what error code 513 is. While better suited as comment, I currently accept it.

Comment: @ThorstenS. You are right there is a little information that is also given in the OP link. I agree it should be a comment on the post.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are trying to create a file in your app's bundle. The bundle is read-only in iOS (and you should treat it as read-only on Mac OS as well, even though it is possible to write to your app bundle in Mac OS.)

Your code will work on the simulator because changing the app bundle **is** allowed on Mac OS, and the simulator runs under Mac OS.

Change your code to use your documents directory, temp directory, or some other directory in your bundle and you should be fine.

Comment: I am pretty sure he doesn't write to his app's bundle, although it's pretty hard to read his code.

Comment: I am not create a file in bundle

Answer (score 1):

I've been thinking about this scenario, and I can't come up with any better suggestion than: `Race Condition`? 
Could it be that two treads are trying to log at the same time? The first one creates the folder directly after the second tread is passing the .fileExistsAtPath check?

- T1: Folder? -> No
- T2: Folder? -> No
- T1: Create
- T2: WTF? There is a folder here already?

If this is the case, it could solve the problem by moving the create directory check and logic to a earlier stage, like on App start or similar.

Not sure this is the issue or that this is the definite answer, so just let's call it a qualified guess... :)

Answer (score 1):

The format you using for getting date string is "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" which introduces a space in the result string. Remove the space in the formatter so that it looks like this  "yyyy-MM-ddHH:mm:ss" and try the above code or you could replace the space in the resulting path and write data to the file