# Simple ImagePicker leads to "Couldn't create log directory"

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, uiimagepickercontroller

I apply very typical approach to use the camera from app

```
@IBAction func takePicture(sender: UIButton) {


var myPickerController = UIImagePickerController()
myPickerController.delegate = self
myPickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera

self.presentViewController(myPickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage!, editingInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]!) {
    self.images = image

    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

However, anytime I use it the following prompt appears in terminal:

> [PLLogging] Couldn't create log directory: The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 513.)

I've already checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3439408/nsfilemanager-creating-folder-cocoa-error-513) and [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30184106/couldnt-create-log-directory) threads and many others but still can't figure out what should be changed.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is your code working? Looks to be some iOS issue. Certainly nothing related directly to the code you posted.

Comment: Yes it is working. This is sample project so I hardly can find any other places that lead to this error, especially that it appears only when photo is taken

Comment: Ignore it. There's nothing you can do about it.

Comment: this is kinda sad that Apple left such *bugs* in their development environment. I'm happy to hear that I can ignore it though

Comment: I am having same issue but with objective-C. Please let me know if you find any solution.