# Create Directory using NSURL

Tags: ios, iphone, nsurl

I'm a new iOS learner.So I want to ask that why i can't get my current path of my project when i'm using `NSFileManager` and `NSURL`.

in file .h i have

```
@property NSString *s_currentPath;
@property NSFileManager *fileman;
```

and this is in my file .m

```
_fileman = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
_s_currentPath = [_fileman currentDirectoryPath];
name = _inputName.text;
NSString *temp = [_s_currentPath  stringByAppendingString:name];
NSURL *newDir = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:temp];
[_fileman createDirectoryAtURL: newDir withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes: nil error:nil];
```

Comment: check for error while creating directory! i got error NSCocoaError Domain 513 means This is the bundle directory containing the application itself. Because an application must be signed, you must not make changes to the contents of this directory at runtime. Doing so may prevent your application from launching later. check Here --> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3439408/nsfilemanager-creating-folder-cocoa-error-513

Comment: there is no errors. the newDir is just nil

Comment: check _s_currentpath and name. As i got new Directory "file:///name"