# Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=513 only when rename folder through UITests target for UI Autoamtion

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, ui-automation, xcuitest

I am developing a product like DropBox and Box application, and I need to verify Rename/Add/Delete I/O operation using automation.

I am writing UI Automation Test Cases using XCUITest in Xcode.
In that I need to use I/O operation for rename file/folder but It gives the below error while using moveItemAtPath function to rename folder:

```
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=513 "“Folder” couldn’t be moved because you don’t have permission to access “Folder1”." UserInfo={NSSourceFilePathErrorKey=*path, NSUserStringVariant=(
Move), NSDestinationFilePath=*destiPath, NSFilePath=*path, NSUnderlyingError=0x6000002507d0 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=1 "Operation not permitted"}}
```

Its working fine when running the app in main target and also its working in UnitTest target but its not working while running UITest automation target.

**NOTE: App Groups are also enabled.**

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the folder you writing to or in your case i dont know why you're renaming the folder. If you've to do something to your folder then perhaps having that folder in one of these locations Documents, Temp and Cache. Most likely, you will want to write to the Documents folder.

It seems to me like a codesign error. Refer this post [NSFileManager creating folder (Cocoa error 513.)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3439408/nsfilemanager-creating-folder-cocoa-error-513)

Comment: I am developing a product like DropBox and Box application, and I need to verify Rename/Add/Delete I/O operation using automation thats why I need to rename folder/file related stuffs. And also doing that i/o operation in particular workspace like "/User/DropBox/"  So I could not use locations like Documents, Temp and Cache. Are you getting me?

Comment: is this running in iOS or macOS? You may be sandboxed out of the path by the OS.

Answer (score 1):

Try this below approach. I'm quoting apple documentation - https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Security/Conceptual/AppSandboxDesignGuide/AppSandboxInDepth/AppSandboxInDepth.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011183-CH3-SW22

**Scenario 1:**
Your app needs to be able to save a file with a different extension than that of the original file. For example, when you paste an image into an RTF file in TextEdit and save it, TextEdit changes the file’s extension from .rtf to .rtfd (and it becomes a directory).

To handle this situation, you must use an **NSFileCoordinator** object to coordinate access to the file. Before you rename the file, call the **itemAtURL:willMoveToURL: method**. After you rename the file, call the **itemAtURL:didMoveToURL: method**.

**Scenario 2:**
Your app needs to be able to open or save multiple related files with the same name and different extensions (for example, to automatically open a subtitle file with the same name as a movie file, or to allow for a SQLite journal file).

To gain access to that secondary file, create a class that conforms to the NSFilePresenter protocol. This object should provide the main file’s URL as its primaryPresentedItemURL property, and should provide the secondary file’s URL as its presentedItemURL property.

After the user opens the main file, your file presenter object should call the addFilePresenter: class method on the NSFileCoordinator class to register itself.

In both scenarios, you must make a small change to the application’s Info.plist file. Your app should already declare a Document Types (CFBundleDocumentTypes) array that declares the file types your app can open.

For each file type dictionary in that array, if that file type should be treated as a potentially related type for open and save purposes, add the key NSIsRelatedItemType with a boolean value of YES.

To learn more about file presenters and file coordinators, read File System Programming Guide.

Comment: I have tried to create and update file/folder using NSFileCoordinator but got same error using that as NSFileManager