# Permission Error - NSCocoaErrorDomain Code: 513 When Exporting iOS 16.0 (20A360) Simulator

Tags: xcode, macos, permissions, ios-simulator

When trying to export an iOS simulator from freshly installed XCode, It fails and prompts: `“63E630E3-EC20-494C-A4EE-58E01194FAC0.dmg” couldn’t be copied because you don’t have permission to access “Documents”`.

Upon trying other locations within my users' directories `<Application_Home>/tmp and <Application_Home>/Library/Caches`, the same prompt is shown (suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3439986/14904053) by @Alex). I also checked by ways of Finder to see the permissions for sanity purposes, and it also stated read/write.

Other ideas I've tried are enabling Full-Disk access for XCode within System Preferences, opening XCode as a superuser through terminal (`sudo open /Applications/Xcode.app`), & outright rebooting the machine. Not sure what to do from here.

```
“63E630E3-EC20-494C-A4EE-58E01194FAC0.dmg” couldn’t be copied because you don’t have permission to access “test”.
Domain: NSCocoaErrorDomain
Code: 513
Failure Reason: You don’t have permission.
Recovery Suggestion: To view or change permissions, select the item in the Finder and choose File > Get Info.
User Info: {
    DVTErrorCreationDateKey = "2007-03-17 01:05:12 +0000";
    NSDestinationFilePath = "/Users/foobar/Desktop/test/iOS-16-0.dmg";
    NSFilePath = "/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Images/63E630E3-EC20-494C-A4EE-58E01194FAC0.dmg";
    NSSourceFilePathErrorKey = "/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Images/63E630E3-EC20-494C-A4EE-58E01194FAC0.dmg";
    NSUserStringVariant =     (
        Copy
    );
}
--
The operation couldn’t be completed. Permission denied
Domain: NSPOSIXErrorDomain
Code: 13
Failure Reason: Permission denied
--


System Information

macOS Version 13.5 (Build 22G74)
Xcode 15.0.1 (22266) (Build 15A507)
Timestamp: 2007-03-17T18:03:04-02:00
```

Comment: Why was the Cocoa tag removed @Willeke? `NSCocoaErrorDomain` I believe is also dealing with Cocoa, no?

Comment: Cocoa is Apple's application-development framework for macOS. I don't see any Cocoa in the question.